# How to manually create a boost ptree with XML attributes?

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I've been using boost libraries to parse XML files and I have to create a ptree manually. I need to add an XML attribute to the ptree.  This is what the boost documentation suggests:

```
ptree pt;
pt.push_back(ptree::value_type("pi", ptree("3.14159")));
```

That adds a element with content, but I also need to add an attribute to the element.

The code above produces:

```
<pi>3.14</pi>
```

I need to add something like this:

```
<pi id="pi_0">3.14</pi>
```

What do I need to change, to add the attribute `id="pi_0"`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use the "fake" node `<xmlattr>`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.xml_parser

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5ff3fb2e6bc2d22)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main() {

    ptree pt;
    pt.push_back(ptree::value_type("pi", ptree("3.14159")));
    pt.put("pi.<xmlattr>.id", "pi_0");

    write_xml(std::cout, pt);
}
```

Prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pi id="pi_0">3.14159</pi>
```

Comment: Note the documentation link :) Boost documentation is frequently terse, but patient.